# Gradle combined flavors doesn't work

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing on Android and have some difficulty with Gradle's build logic.

I'm trying to have a set of resources and java files for a combined flavors.

I put them in a folder `src/productFlavor1ProductFlavor2/`

But when I compile the build variant `productFlavor1ProductFlavor2DevDebug` , it simply doesn't get anything from the `productFlavor1ProductFlavor2` folder.

I tried pretty much everything...
From the syntax and order:

```
src/productFlavor1ProductFlavor2/
src/productFlavor1productFlavor2/
src/productFlavor1-productFlavor2/
src/productFlavor1/ProductFlavor2/
```

To trying to indicate the folder to gradle

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
if (variant.getProductFlavors().get(0).name.equals('productFlavor1')
   && variant.getProductFlavors().get(1).name.equals('productFlavor2'))
    variant.sourceSets = 'src/productFlavor1ProductFlavor2'//read only... so doesn't work
}
```

Anyone knows why the combination of flavors indicated in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/ doesn't actually work....? Or if I'm missing somethine there...

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to define multiple dimensions of flavors.
It is not allowed to combine the single flavor dimensions.

I don't think it is a good idea to put source code to multi-flavor folders anyway as you are getting too many combinations to take care of.

If I were on your place, I would treat every dimension separately instead ie:
have a separate folder with productFlavor1 & productFlavor2.

Check this out: [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants), [overview of build system](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/).

The priority order for the different folders:
1. build variant (fully qualified name, like debugFlavor1Flavor2/src)
1. build type (debug/src)
1. product flavor (if you have multiple dimensions they ordered in order of declaration)
1. main/src